# Is this inference from Rolle's Theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, rolles-theorem

In a script I'm reading right now that is providing a proof for Cauchy's mean value theorem (extended mean value theorem), it says

"We have $g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in ]a,b[$ (otherwise, there would be a point $x_0\in]a,b[$ with $g^{\prime} = 0$ - which is a contradiction)"

The contradiction stems from the fact that we stated $g^{\prime} \neq 0$ before, I'm just really wondering about the string of thought. Does Rolle's Theorem really suggest that if a function goes through zero, it must have an extremum (which wouldn't make sense to me). Thanks for any hints on if I'm missing something.

Comment: What is the function $g$ in the context of this proof?

Comment: Let $f, g: ]a,b[ \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, with $g^{\prime}(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in ]a,b[$. Furthermore, we have $lim_{x \searrow a} f(x) = lim_{x \searrow a} g(x) = 0$ or $ lim_{x \searrow a} f(x) = lim_{x \searrow a} g(x) = \infty $

Comment: This is not enough to apply Rolle's theorem.

Comment: The proof begins by stating: "Let $f(a) = g(a) = 0$, then $f,g: [a,b[ \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous." But how would that help?

Comment: Sorry, just realized my mistake, thanks for making me think about it more.

Comment: You have $g(a)=0$. If $g(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in (a,b)$, then Rolle's theorem applies.

Comment: Thanks, @amsmath.